# Antlr4 mismatch input (partial match)

Tags: regex, parsing, antlr, antlr4

In ANTLR4 I have the following grammar:

```
ID : [_a-zA-Z][0-9_a-zA-Z]*;
INT_LITERAL : [0-9]+;
FLOAT_LITERAL :[0-9]+'.'?[0-9]*([eE][-+]?)?[0-9]+;
```

When parsing the string 123abc, I'm expecting an error but instead I get the tokens:

```
123
abc
<EOF>
```

I've tried to add `EOF` at the end of my int and float literal regex,

```
INT_LITERAL : [0-9]+EOF;
FLOAT_LITERAL :[0-9]+'.'?[0-9]*([eE][-+]?)?[0-9]+EOF;
```

but even then I still get some partial parsing result

```
bc
<EOF>
```

What should I modify in order to make my grammar not accept the string `123abc`?

Comment: Try using word boundaries `\b` like `\b[_a-zA-Z][0-9_a-zA-Z]*\b` or anchors `^` and `$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird those anchors are not valid in ANTLR unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lexer produces the correct result.

This type of errors should be handled in a parser, not a lexer. Do you have a parser rule that accepts `INT_LITERAL` followed by `ID`? I guess you don't. Let the parser do its job. If the rule is missing, the error you're expecting will be thrown, but only at the parsing phase, not lexical analysis.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, just to be clear you are referring to parser rules like this ```program  : 'class' ID LP RP EOF; ``` ?

Comment: @SoyänChardon, yes, the rules, used by a parser. You can read more about it here: [Grammar Structure](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/grammars.md)